# Implementing triangle, sawtooth and reverse sawtooth formulas in program code

Tags: math, trigonometry

I've looked at the formulas for these waves but I can't figure out how to implement them. I was able to figure you the SINE and SQUARE waves:

```
float x = note.frequency / AppSettings::sampleRate;
float theta_increment = 2.0f * M_PI * x;
float value = 0;

if(waveType == SINE){
    value = sin(theta_increment);
}
else if (waveType == SQUARE){
    value = sin(note.theta);
    value = (value > 0) - (value < 0);
}
```

The formula I tried was [based on this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3399925/393964) and the explanation from wiki:

```
square(t) = sgn(sin(2πt))

// this is how I tried to implement it
theta_increment - floor(theta_increment - 0.5f);
```

But this generates a very low sounding tone and the frequency change doesn't seem to have any effect (not one that I can hear anyway). So cans someone help me with implementing sawtooth and triangle? Some explanation would be very helpful to because unlike sine and square I don't understand these formulas very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delphi code. I hope that formulas are clear. Frequencies and magnitudes are consistent.

```
  w := 1.0;   // angular frequency
  for i := 0 to 999 do begin
    t := i * 2 * Pi / 400 - 3/2 * Pi; // just X-axis scale
    wt := w * t;
    f := wt / (2.0 * Pi); //frequency

    sn := sin(wt);                      // sine wave

    saw := 2.0 * (f - Floor(f)) - 1.0;  //sawtooth

    f := f + 0.25;
    tr := Abs(4 * (f - Floor(f + 0.5))) - 1.0;  //triangle

    Series1.AddXY(t, sn);
    Series2.AddXY(t, saw);
    Series3.AddXY(t, tr);
  end;
```

Result:

[image]